# Effect of magnesium hydroxide MgOH formation in water on pH (Why more basic?)

Tags: ph, alkaline-earth-metals

Elemental magnesium reacts in (hot) water to form magnesium hydroxide and hydrogen gas:

$$\ce{Mg_{(s)} + H2O_{(g)} -> Mg(OH)2_{(s)} + H2_{(g)}}$$

[As indicated for example by phenolphthalein turning pink (Youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SjZaZeAJrA), this increases pH. Why?

I would assume that magnesium hydroxide as a strong base dissolves back to yield hydroxide anions, but those are previously taken away from the water, so isn't the net effect neutral? My assumption is that magnesium makes water dissociate at higher rate than it would be by itself, and that formation of hydrogen gas binds/removes protons from the solution, while the hydroxide dissociates back to the solution, therefore net making it basic. Does that add up or is the main reason another?

Comment: $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ is "strong weak base", but just slighly soluble, with equilibrium $\ce{Mg(OH)2(s) <<=>[H2O]Mg^2+(aq) + 2 OH-(aq)}$ with trace amounts of   $\ce{Mg(OH)+(aq)}$ and $\ce{Mg(OH)2(aq)}$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to copy your assumptions as printed in the text (*in italics*) and then add my comments and answers in the text (but not in italics), as one goes along. Let's go !

*I would assume that magnesium hydroxide as a strong base dissolves back to yield hydroxide anions* This is right.  *but those are previously taken away from the water, so isn't the net effect neutral?* What does it mean ? The hydroxide anions remain in water, at least at low concentrations, when the solution is not yet saturated in $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$. Why do you think that they are "taken away from the water" ? *My assumption is that magnesium makes water dissociate at higher rate than it would be by itself*, Well ! Hot water is more dissociated than cold water, but this is natural, and not due to magnesium or any other solute. *and that formation of hydrogen gas binds/removes protons from the solution*, *while the hydroxide dissociates back to the solution, therefore net making it basic. Does that add up or is the main reason another?* This is right. The solution gets more basic.